# Pipe operator in java 7

Tags: java, operators, pipe

I saw recently in a code example the following:

```
f.setExtendedState( f.getExtendedState()|JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH );
```

where f is a JFrame. How is this pipe operator called, what does it do and where can I find documentation about it?

Thank you
Héctor

Comment: Voting to close as it is a duplicate.

Comment: I'm sorry guys, I didn't realize this was a bitwise XOR operator, seems weird to me to use it like this, but thanks for the answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `|` operator is the [bitwise-or operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) in Java.

The result of a bitwise-or is a value with bits set in it if the corresponding bit was set in either of the operands (or both).

Here, this operation uses the value of `JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH` (in binary, `0000 0110`) to ensure that the second to last and third to last bits are turned on, one for horizontal and one for vertical.  This leaves all other bits from `f.getExtendedState()` intact.

Answer (score 2):

That 'pipe' is actually a bitwise inclusive or. f.getExtendedState() and JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH are probably number indexes in bitfields. using the 'or' operator combines the properties of both into one value.

Comment: Useful answer to me. But why is it necessary to do a bitwise inclusive to maximize a JFrame? I tested this method just using JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH and it maximizes my JFrame.

Comment: `f.getExtendedState()` returns the current state of that frame so doing that bitwise operation maximizes it without disrupting the existing state. Using just `JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH` would reset any other attribute in the bitfield.

Answer (score 0):

| stands for bitwise inclusive OR operater. Check for details here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html

Answer (score 0):

The pipe (|) operator is simply *bitwise-or* operator. It will go through the respective bits of two numbers, and the resulting number will have an on bit where either of the two input bits were on. In the case you gave us, the operator is used to *add a flag* to a bitfield.

For example, if you have a number `flags`, which (let's say) is 4, it would look like

```
00000100b
```

in binary. If you `|` it with the number `00010000b` (16), the result is

```
00010100b,
```

which contains the original flag (at bit position 3) and the new flag (at bit position 5).